# CMS - How to work with multiple environments? Do I really need them?

Tags: sqlite, content-management-system, orchardcms

I've never worked with any CMS and I simply wanted to play with such ones. As originally I come from .NET roots, so I was thinking about choosing Orchard Core CMS.

Let's imagine very simple scenario, together with my colleague I'd like to create a blog. As I'm used to work with web based systems and applications for a business for me it's kinda normal to work with code repository, having multiple environments dev/test/stage/prod, implementing CI / CD, adjusting database via migrations or scripts.

Now the question is do I need all of this with working on our blog with a usage of CMS.

To be more specific I can ask few questions:

1. Shall I create blog using CMS locally (My PC) -> create few articles and then deploy it to the web or I should create a blog over the internet and add articles in prod environment directly.
2. How to synchronize databases between environments (dev / prod).

I can add, that as I do not expect many visitors on a website I was thinking to use Orchard Core CMS together with SQLite. Also I expect that I can customize code, add new modules, extend existing ones etc. - not only add content (articles). You can take that into consideration in answering the question

So basically my question is what should be the workflow of a person who want to create / administer and maintain CMS (let it be blog) as a single person or as a team.

Shall I work and create content locally, then publish it and somehow synchronize both application and database (database is my main question mark - also in a context how to do that properly using SQLite).

Or simply all the changes - code + content should be managed directly on a server let's call it production environment.

Excuse me if question is silly and hard to understand, but I'm looking for any advice as I really didn't find any good examples / information about that or maybe I'm seeking in totally wrong direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question, not at all silly ;)

When dealing with a CMS, you need to think about the data/content in very different terms from the code/modules, despite the fact that the boundary between them is not always completely obvious.

For Orchard, the recommendation is not to install modules in production, but to have a dev - staging - production type of environment: install new modules on a dev environment, test them in staging, and then deploy to production when it's safe to do so. Depending on the scale of the project, the staging may be skipped for a more agile dev to prod setting but the idea remains the same, and is not very different from any modular application.

Then you have the activation and configuration of the settings of the modules you deploy. Because in a CMS like Orchard, those settings are considered data and stored in the database, they should be handled like content. This includes metadata such as the very shape of the content of your site: content types are data.

Data is typically not deployed like code is, with staging and prod environments (although it can, to a degree, more on that in a moment). One reason for this is that a CMS will often feature user-provided data, such as reviews, ratings, comments or usage stats. Synchronizing all that two-ways is very impractical. Another even more important reason is that the very reason to use a CMS is to let non-technical owners of the site manage content themselves in a fast and direct manner.

The difference between code and data is also visible in the way you secure their changes: for code, usual source control is still the rule, whereas for the content, you'll setup database backups.

Also important to mention is the structure of the database. You typically don't have to worry about this until you write your own modules: Orchard comes with a rich data migration feature that makes sure the database structure gets updated with the code that uses it. So don't worry about that, the database will just update itself as you deploy code to production.

Finally, I must mention that some CMS sites do need to be able to stage contents and test it before exposing it to end-users. There are variations of that: in some cases, being able to draft and preview content items is enough. Orchard supports that out of the box: any content type can be marked draftable. When that is not enough, there is an optional feature called Deployments that enables rich content deployment workflows that can be repeated, scheduled and validated. An important point concerning that module is that the deployment only applies to the subset of the site's content you decide it should apply to (and excludes, obviously, stuff like user-provided content).

So in summary, treat code and modules as something you deploy in a one-way fashion from the dev box all the way to production, with ordinary source control and deployment methods, and treat data depending on the scenario, from simple direct in production database instances with a good backup policy, to drafts stored in production, and then all the way to complex content deployment rules.